# Inheritance. Why this output?

Tags: c++

the following program prints 3 and 4, but i can't understand it. can anyone explains me step by step why i have this output??

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
      public: 
              int f(int x){
                        cout << x << " " << endl;
              }
};

class B : public A{
      public:
              int f(int y){
                        A :: f(y+1);
              }
};

void g(A a, B b){
     a.f(3), b.f(3);
}

int main(){
    B p; 
    B q; 
    g(p,q);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't print that. You must be running some other program.

Comment: See this [online example](https://ideone.com/iI7X6x). for me it prints 3 and 4

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have no virtual functions and thus the functions from the corresponding class will be called. Thus you simply call `a::f(3)` and `B::f(3)`. Second even if f **was** virtual you pass the arguments of `g` by value which means a upcast happens and thus in `g` you simply have an instance of `A` and instance of `B`, no polymorphism involved. Thus the [output](http://ideone.com/ctW2GE) is:

```
3
4
```

Not very surprising.

Comment: OP gets -13 12 and 25 as output, which IS surprising

Comment: @MatthiasB I've put a link to the very same code being executed on ideone.

Comment: I did the same, and apparently OP made a mistake there (as the question is updated now). Just saying the answer would not have been of much value if OP output was genuine...

Comment: My downvote: When this answer was posted, the question (specifically the expected output of OP) was different. Now, as the question was changed, this answer is correct and I'd remove a downvote, but the SO mechanics do not allow to remove a downvote if the answer was not changed.

Comment: @MatthiasB we should request that changed on meta. Answer is not changed but question is.  I will do a small edit for now